# How to set bluetooth to remain disabled after suspend?

Tags: suspend, bluetooth

Bluetooth is enabled by default, and I don't want that since I rarely use it and it consumes battery.

I know you can enter

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

in `/etc/rc.local`, which works upon reboot. But the bluetooth becomes enabled again whenever I resume from suspend. How do I fix that?

Comment: I aslo need to block Bluetooth after suspend, because of this networking bug that breaks wifi: http://askubuntu.com/a/632879/48382. If bluetooth is on, wifi won't work. — I need to block bluetooth both after reboot and after suspend.

Comment: @KajMagnus This question has been dead for years. Please ask a new question that includes all the necessary details. Thanks!