# Cannot Connect To WiFi - Intel Corporation Wireless 3160

Tags: wireless, 15.04

I got a new laptop recently and since 14.04 refused to work and 12.04 is a little dated I installed Ubuntu 15.04 Beta 2. Anyways, I've been looking around and cannot find a way to get the wifi to connect. It tries to connect for a while but then gives up after a while. Ethernet works and BT Hub 1 worked, however I can no longer try it with that hub. Hub 2 and 3 don't work. I tried following [this guide](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-3160-ucode-22.15.8.0.tgz) but it's still having the same issue. I also ran some script of sorts at some point. Maybe this means something to someone out there? :

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 05 Apr 2015 13:58 BST +0100

Booted last: 05 Apr 2015 13:53 BST +0100

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Vivid Vervet (development branch)
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-10-generic #10-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 23 16:25:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:3821 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:00f6 Microsoft Corp. Comfort Optical Mouse 1000
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                275408  0 
mac80211              720010  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               194687  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              539517  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.88  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:feb5:42c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26409639 (26.4 MB)  TX bytes:1285849 (1.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### nm-tool ###########################

./wireless_script: line 198: nm-tool: command not found

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'BTHomeSpot-JGK' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BTHomeSpot-JGK"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001f8c326bbc1
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'VM479590-2G' [AC2]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VM479590-2G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000098e4f3f0363
                    Extra: Last beacon: 11168ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

57000101103B000103104700101592C7058D485A0FA75E0FEB32983A12102100074E65746765617210230007564D444734383510240007564D44473438351042000D334257323337553330324533461054000800060050F204000110110007564D444734383510080002210C103C0001011049000600372A000120
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BTHub3-ZHRQ"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000ad63c832cd
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-10-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     88D1E879FA8C28657F76FF4
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-10-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        06:37:5D:B6:08:53:4C:1D:80:60:BF:25:63:59:2F:F3:EA:34:BE:B3
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-10-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     F518BE1BD732F328C9E430B
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-10-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        06:37:5D:B6:08:53:4C:1D:80:60:BF:25:63:59:2F:F3:EA:34:BE:B3
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-10-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode
srcversion:     ADFD966DF2A9D56EE93BE48
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-10-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        06:37:5D:B6:08:53:4C:1D:80:60:BF:25:63:59:2F:F3:EA:34:BE:B3
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-10-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     268045EBCFAFDADD136DCF6
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-10-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        06:37:5D:B6:08:53:4C:1D:80:60:BF:25:63:59:2F:F3:EA:34:BE:B3
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

coretemp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b3 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    8.838726] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[    8.838779] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[    8.989030] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   10.391159] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq
[   10.534470] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[   19.977713] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[   23.534661] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]>
[   23.537874] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[   23.591139] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 2/3)
[   23.667389] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 3/3)
[   23.736857] wlan0: authentication with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> timed out
[   27.278073] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]>
[   27.281208] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[   27.368189] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 2/3)
[   27.433090] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 3/3)
[   27.504012] wlan0: authentication with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> timed out
[   31.446683] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]>
[   31.449111] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[   31.512377] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 2/3)
[   31.578691] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 3/3)
[   31.613611] wlan0: authentication with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> timed out
[   36.058901] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]>
[   36.061601] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[   36.122069] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 2/3)
[   36.155863] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 3/3)
[   36.218568] wlan0: authentication with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> timed out
[   48.062942] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]>
[   48.065316] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[   48.125589] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 2/3)
[   48.175991] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> (try 3/3)
[   48.235686] wlan0: authentication with <MAC 'BTHub3-ZHRQ' [AC3]> timed out

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Uninformatively Ask Ubuntu does not provide support for development versions of Ubuntu. You may want to report a bug for this issue. Check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for more information on how to do so.

Comment: You might just have to set the wifi router to WPA2-AES or WPA2 only and it seems that `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` helps also

Comment: @Fabby I don't know if it is a bug though.

Comment: Just noticed - Thanks Michael for fixing the text. Wasn't sure how to get it into the funky box.  :P

Comment: Close vote retracted...

Comment: @Jeremy31 Changing the hub to WPA2 only or WEP results in the wifi still failing to connect. The open BT-Wifi-with-FON in my area isn't working either.

Comment: It should be able to load the ver 12 firmware https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-3160-ucode-25.16.12.0.tgz or do you already have it `ls /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi-3160`

Comment: You will likely have to change the ver 12 name to let it load.  In terminal from wherever you extracted the file to `sudo cp iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode` then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 Running `ls /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi-3160` results in the following output:
`iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode`.
Running `sudo cp iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode` results in `cp: cannot stat ‘iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode’: No such file or directory`. Now I'm just confused. By the way, is there a way to enter new lines in a comment? This is really bugging me.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for the ctrl+shift+p tip. Never knew you could copy/paste in the terminal with the keyboard! What I entered into the terminal did not have a space anyway.  :/

Comment: `sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode`  Reboot,  I saw you must have edited your comment so I deleted mine

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks - rebooting now.

Comment: @Jeremy31 All is working now. Thanks!  :P

Answer (score 4):

Credit goes to Jeremy for this.

To fix the problem, pasting in `sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode` is required. Not sure if anything else is needed, other than rebooting.

Comment: After looking at the source code for that kernel, the rename shouldn't have been needed, you should have been able to copy iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode into /lib/firmware/ and it should have worked after a reboot.

Comment: This works, can you please explain this solution?

Comment: @user99319 I have no idea; all I know is that that command is renaming it from _iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode_ to _iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode_. Probably an incorrect name messing things up or something.

Comment: Not working here. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Flatron, try to change the number to `15` instead of `10`. Does it work? For me the above solution didn't work either, but somehow 15 did.

Comment: @Flatron test to disable Bluetooth and reboot. See my answer.

Comment: What made you think that 15 would work instead of 10?

Comment: I've tried everything above but none worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Disable bluetooth and reboot. That's what worked for me. (Intel Wireless 3160 (rev 93), kernel 3.19.0-18, Linux Mint 17.1)

I disable bluetooth by launching the start menu and typing "bluetooth". Then a bluetooth settings program appears.

This: `sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode` had no effect, for me. (And neither using 15 instead of 10 as a comment suggests.)

Here is an issue about a bug that apparently is the source of the problems (in my case at least):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1442411

> [Workaround]
>
> Boot with bluetooth turned off. If the computer boots with the
>   bluetooth turned on, the wifi will not work, even if you first turn
>   off the bluetooth. A restart is needed.

Now the next problem: How do I make Bluetooth stay disabled after suspend? Here is a question about that but it's been closed as too localized: [How to set bluetooth to remain disabled after suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/q/86368/48382) — I think it's no longer too localized. ... I'm testing this now: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211&p=9155208#post9155208  -- edit: it worked, like so: (this isn't exactly what they posted in the forum — seems as if I had to change it a bit, and `block` not `unblock` after resume)

```
16:10:40 3 ~$ cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_bluetooth__kajmagnus 
#!/bin/bash
# Code from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211

# Turns **off** Bluetooth after suspend. I hope it does.

. /usr/lib/pm-utils/functions

case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        rfkill block bluetooth
        ;;
    thaw|resume)
        # This unblocks:
        # rfkill unblock bluetooth
        # But I need to turn it off because of a network bug, so:  [kajmagnus]
        rfkill block bluetooth
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

exit
```

Comment: Exactly. Disabling  bluetooth and rebooting worked for me . Did you find any permanent solution ?

Comment: @SoulMan I haven't searched for any other solutions. I still have Bluetooth disabled, don't need it right now anyway

Comment: @SoulMan Or did you mean a permanent way to disable Bluetooth? Yes, I updated my answer

Comment: Sorry I meant having wifi working even with Brluetooth on while booting. Actually one of my wifi is working when I boot with BT on.

Comment: Workaround doesn't seem to work for me 

Answer (score 0):

None of the mentioned solution worked for me.
Fortunately, I have fixed the wifi issue in my Lenovo T440p laptop by just upgrading my linux kernel to 4.x as mentioned in the below post - [Install Linux Kernel 4.0.3](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/05/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-0-3-in-linux.html)

Comment: Upgrading didn't help at all. Rather gave a bunch of errors at the system start

Comment: My solution might not have worked as the version you are trying could be different, Wish you didn't downvote.

Answer (score 0):

**Updating the Kernel to 4.4** was the only way that I could resolve my issue. I updated it using the Synaptic Package Manager, and all went well.

I am still using Ubuntu 14.04 by making use of [Canonical's Extended Maintenance Service](https://ubuntu.com/advantage).

All this while since April, 2018, I'd pinned my Kernel to 3.13.0-147-generic, because updating to 3.13.0-149-generic caused issue with my laptop's (Dell Inspiron 5558) Suspend/Resume feature. I'd posted a question back then regarding this issue here: [Experiencing Suspend/Resume Problem After Latest Kernel Update - Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040169/experiencing-suspend-resume-problem-after-latest-kernel-update-ubuntu-14-04).

Today once again, while trying to configure Canonical's Extended Maintenance Service, I tried to update the kernel. It got updated to 3.13.0-175 but I started experiencing issues with WiFi and external mouse/keyboards connected via USB.

After several research & trial/error, I bumped into this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/623774/356228). Also, I'd to update to Kernel 4.4 as that was the only way Canonical would allow me to apply their **livepatch service**, and that was how I could still keep my Ubuntu 14.04 secured, and boy did it work!

**So anybody still using Ubuntu 14.04 as of Dec 2019, do give this a shot. Should help!**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and kernel 3.19.5 (I know, unsupported... unfortunately the only kernel where I could tweak the psmouse/synaptics module to work with my Trackpoint Buttons on my Thinkpad T450s - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1414930).

I had two firmware files under /lib/modules: iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode and iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode). "lshw -c network" showed that the firmware=25.16.12.0 was loaded, but connecting to WiFi didn't work with "authentication timed out".

After removing "/lib/modules/iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode" and copying "/lib/modules/iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode to /lib/modules/iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode", it started working again! Very strange....

Answer (score -1):

I updated to 15.04 and detected the same problem.

Disabling and reenabling the wifi device recovered the wifi for me.

Basically:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```