# Wifi stopped working after update to 15.04

Tags: wireless

I can still see the wifi networks that are available and attempt to connect to them but the connection doesn't work. I'm using a laptop and I have connected to these networks successfully before the update. The wired networking works fine. Please help me. What other information do I need to post ?

Comment: try reinstalling the driver possibly... post the ouput of `lspci`.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: Here is my info: file:///home/lipresume/wireless-info.txt

Comment: Please go back to the link for running the script and read how to post the file. Thanks

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10973755/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in your terminal as suggested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611222/cannot-connect-to-wifi-intel-corporation-wireless-3160) thread:

`sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode`

Comment: It says there is no such directory.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was:
1. Plug in ethernet cable
2. Turn off wifi (from gnome panel / from hardware button)
3. Restart

After login, turn on wifi and try to connect wifi network

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it also affected my mouse - couldn't use mouse or connect to wifi.  All devices were found, but I was getting a bunch of errors.

Turned out that I reset BIOS to factory defaults (then updated them to what I thought I needed) and this was my problem.  I had to go back into the BIOS and find a little setting called "IOMMU".  Enabling this solved all my issues.

I found this out by looking in dmesg and finding a little nugget that said something like "couldn't find MMU... disabling.  blah blah...".
Once it was enabled, the irq remapping gets enabled and (i guess) the IRQs don't bash anymore.

Anyways - hope this helps others in a similar situation.