# No connection / sporatic connection with Intel 3160 Wireless, Lenovo Y50, Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, lenovo, intel-wireless

I recently bought a Lenovo Y50-70 laptop, and while Ubuntu has mostly been running well I've had issues with the wireless.

Wifi will connect perfectly fine, and it will usually be able to load webpages for about 30 seconds after boot, but then it becomes completely unable to receive anything at all. Occaisionally it will regain the connection for a few seconds, but this happens rarely and for only a few seconds.

Wireless card is Intel 3160 Wireless, and works perfectly fine on Windows (Windows 8.1).

- rfkill - nothing blocked
- lshw -c network - product: Wireless 3160, firmware=25.17.12.0
- kernel version 4.0.3

I should note that I've already tried the solutions presented in the following posts, but none of them have worked so far:

[Cannot Connect To WiFi - Intel Corporation Wireless 3160](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611222/cannot-connect-to-wifi-intel-corporation-wireless-3160)

[Ubuntu Intel wireless 3160 AC not working/slow/disconnecting/unstable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540580/ubuntu-intel-wireless-3160-ac-not-working-slow-disconnecting-unstable)

[Wifi stopped working after update to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617353/wifi-stopped-working-after-update-to-15-04?lq=1)

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192363

So far, downloading a newer kernel, downloading a newer firmware, disabling bluetooth, renaming firmware, setting options as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/541118/423045) haven't worked.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I hope you didn't do the "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1" step. It is quite incorrect. If you need a repair, please post back.

Comment: @chili555: I hadn't at the time I posted that, missed that step, but saw that I missed it shortly afterwards and went ahead and tried it (before you posted). Believe it or not, it's working great now. Mind explaining what's incorrect about it, and should I revert that?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: I am on the same page. Went through all steps posted here without luck. Thanks for sharing possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command in the post you linked is:

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

It will over-write the existing text in the file /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf. It should have read:

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

The '-a' modifier appends the new text to the end of the existing file.

In Ubuntu 15.04, the default file reads:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

That text is necessary to properly unload and reload the module `iwlwifi` if necessary. I suggest you do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Copy and paste the text I included above the line you added. When you are done, it should read like this:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. You should be all set.