# Intel 3160 WiFi not working on 12.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, lenovo, intel-wireless

I am trying to get my Lenovo Edge 15 laptop to recognize the Intel 3160 Wifi firmware.

Found the firmware here:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

Installed different versions of ucode after renaming the olds ones and I am not getting any luck.

Renamed the old code, restarted.

Tried these solutions:

- [No connection / sporatic connection with Intel 3160 Wireless, Lenovo Y50, Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640178/no-connection-sporatic-connection-with-intel-3160-wireless-lenovo-y50-ubuntu)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214075
- Disabled bluetooth, and still nothing.

I am fresh out of options at this point. :( Forgive me if I missed something crucial.

Here is my response from when I ran the command:

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi

filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
alias:          iwlagn
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
srcversion:     F6A04975B757267E0AD9EB4
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000466bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000893sv*sd00000266bc*sc*i*
```

UPDATE: This is what I got when running different versions of the kernel

```
root@tacos-Lenovo-Edge-15:~# dmesg|grep iwlwifi
[   19.537154] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode failed with error -2
[   19.601097] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3160-11.ucode failed with error -2
[   19.698771] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v12, firmware is v0.
[   19.890696] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v12, firmware is v7.
[   19.890766] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[  337.993120] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode failed with error -2
[  337.993128] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3160-11.ucode failed with error -2
[  337.993340] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v12, firmware is v0.
[  337.993510] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v12, firmware is v7.
[  337.993523] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through this same trouble with a new laptop with intel 3165 wifi.  I found that installing a kernel version later than 4.2 made the wifi work.  Some advice (learn from my frustrations):

- Install the "linux-generic" package that corresponds with the kernel version you want.  This way you will know you are getting a full kernel update, with all the extras that you need.
- You might have to try more than one kernel version before you find the one that works best for you (especially if you have intel graphics, which are glitchy in some kernel versions).
- Removing the "linux-generic" package will not remove the other packages it brings with it.  If you want to remove a specific kernel version, you will also need to remove the "linux-headers-x.x.x-xx", "linux-headers-x.x.x-xx-generic", "linux-image-x.x.x-xx-generic" and "linux-image-extra-x.x.x-xx-generic" packages.
- GRUB will boot to the newest kernel version you have installed by default.
- You do need to restart for the new kernel version to take effect.

For reference, I am running Linux Mint 17.3 (Ubuntu 14.04 base) with the "linux-generic-lts-wily" headers package, and everything is working well.

Comment: Okay I am going to keep on trying. I am not sure. I might just fresh install to 14.04, because I am currently on 12.02.

Comment: Yeah, you may need to do a 14.04 install, since there is no package for kernel version 4.2 in the repositories for 12.04.

Comment: Yah the problem was 14.04, I just reinstalled and the wifi and bluetooth was recognized. Thanks for the help!