# Wifi problem, Windows works, tried a lot! authenticating -> associating

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I can not connect to my Wi-Fi, can someone please help or give a hint? I googled a lot. The network manager gets stuck at: "configuring interface".

After a lots of tries I get two messages: 1. wireless network deactivated. 2. no secrets were provided. It also keeps repeating to enter the password.

Wifi chip: Intel 3160 rev cb OS: Ubuntu 15.04

Log file with only the important part: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=71320239466069844799

I tried changing some settings in OpenWRT:
Tried different width (20 Mhz to 40 Mhz)
Tried different channels (11 and 13) 
Tried accesspoint, ad hoc
Tried no ecryption, wpa-psk (with force CCMP (AES) and auto), wpa2-psk

I think this part from the logfile is most important:

```
kernel: [ 1064.946076] wlan0: authenticate with 74:ea:3a:db:21:52
kernel: [ 1064.948713] wlan0: send auth to 74:ea:3a:db:21:52 (try 1/3)

NetworkManager[661]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
kernel: [ 1065.044535] wlan0: send auth to 74:ea:3a:db:21:52 (try 2/3)
kernel: [ 1065.116197] wlan0: send auth to 74:ea:3a:db:21:52 (try 3/3)
May 14 22:32:57 laptop kernel: [ 1065.199438] wlan0: authentication with 74:ea:3a:db:21:52 timed out

wpa_supplicant[809]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Home" auth_failures=1 duration=10

NetworkManager[661]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected

wpa_supplicant[809]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
NetworkManager[661]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

NetworkManager[661]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.

NetworkManager[661]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]
```

Comment: Also tried the new version 4 kernel...
Trying Ubuntu 14.04 now...

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Live WiFi works... But I want to use 15.04. Who knows what could be the problem?

Comment: iwlwifi-3160-9 is the highest wifi driver in ubuntu 14.04... Maybe ubuntu 15.04 has a higher one which is not compatible?

Comment: Why not use 14.04 LTS then, if you have issues with 15.04?

Comment: Here I found  a bug that seems related to this (same error message, Intel 3160): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1453701 — someone tested kernel 4.1 RC2 and said it works (but I don't want to use an unstable RC kernel).

Comment: @romusters In my case, the workaround here solved my problem, without having to use kernel 4.1: http://askubuntu.com/questions/611222/cannot-connect-to-wifi-intel-corporation-wireless-3160/632879#632879 — namely disable Bluetooth and reboot.

Comment: @KajMagnus thank you! Will try in a couple of weeks (too much of a hassle now).

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if connectivity is improved.

Answer (score -1):

Possible, you have configured Mac Filter on you WiFi router.

In your log I see:

```
May 14 22:32:45 laptop kernel: [ 1053.150123] wlan0: authenticate with 74:ea:3a:db:21:52
May 14 22:32:45 laptop kernel: [ 1053.152547] wlan0: send auth to 74:ea:3a:db:21:52 (try 1/3)
```

This means your wifi adapter trying to send it's mac address to router for authenticate.

Disable Mac filtering on your router or allow device with mac address "74:ea:3a:db:21:52" to get access.

After that, reconnect to your "Home" network.