# Home wifi does not work - 15.04 Lenovo Z510

Tags: wireless, 15.04

After I upgrade to 15.04 from 14.04 (though not immediately after I updated), my home internet did not work anymore. It connected, but when I tried to go to a webpage an error is given by the browser. 
This error is:

dns probe finished bad config

Only my home internet does not work. However it does work on every other device I have.

I tried what they said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611222/cannot-connect-to-wifi-intel-corporation-wireless-3160) but that did not help. Some information:

kernel: 4.0.3-040003-generic

```
boudewijn@boudewijn-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:~$ lspci

09:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

boudewijn@boudewijn-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I hope someone can help me! :)

Comment: Did you try it with a supported kernel? And what does `rfkill list show`?

Comment: I do not know what you mean with a supported kernel. I get: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: The blocks of information I try to put up, I cant get them to look very good, sorry

Comment: Try #2: Did you try to boot with a supported Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: Like I said I dont know what you mean with that, and how I do that.

Comment: Why do you have kernel 4.0.3-040003-generic? This kernel is not supported in Ubuntu. You either have another distro, or installed an unsupported kernel yourself.

Comment: See last post by Jeyanthan I in http://askubuntu.com/questions/611222/cannot-connect-to-wifi-intel-corporation-wireless-3160. Before I had a supported kernel but it did not work at that time either.