# Experiencing Suspend/Resume Problem After Latest Kernel Update - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates, suspend

I am experiencing suspend/resume issues after updating my kernel to the latest versions viz. **3.13.0-149-generic**. Since 2015, and until Kernel version **3.13.0-147-generic**, everything was working fine. But now after the latest kernel update, whenever I suspend my Dell 5558 laptop, I am unable to resume; restarting is the only solution.

Specs:

- **Ubuntu Version**: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS - x64
- **Kernel**: 3.13.0-149-generic
- **Laptop:** Dell 5558

Note: Whenever I revert to my backup copy (one that doesn't contain this update) that I've created using Timeshift everything is normal.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I've filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774150

Comment: @donnek - have you been able to arrive at any solution? 

As for myself, I have reverted to 147 and pinned this kernel version so that my system no longer updates to a newer kernel version, and now everything is working fine.

 Anyway in the coming months I will have to abandon 14.04 as this is the last year it will be supported, so didn't scratch my head much trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: After downgrading intel-microcode from 3.20180425.1 (trusty-security update) to previous version 2.20140122.1, wakeup after suspend finally works again for me...

Comment: To revert I used synaptic and its "force version" option in the package menu after  searching/selecting the intel-microcode package (plus the option to block version against update after that). The hardest part for me was to obtain a precisely timed list of updates to sort the (few) possibly bad ones.

Comment: I tried just updating the Kernel while ignoring the intel-microcode update, and yet again I experienced the suspend/resume failure. Eventually, I have decided to continue to pin my kernel updates, as anyway, in the coming months I will have to upgrade to 18.04.

For this particular issue, I have decided to go with the popular norm 'If it ain't broke don't fix it.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just answered a related solution to a similar issue here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1194066/356228. Found the solution why trying to setup **Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) for Ubuntu 14.04**.