# De-suspend failure after 3.13.0-149

Tags: suspend

I am still using 14.04 (which still seems to be maintained, to my surprise).

Last week, it upgraded my kernel to Linux 3.13.0-149-generic. Since then I have the following problem:

I normally Suspend when not using the machine, with a request to de-suspend at 0400 each morning to do various housekeeping tasks. Since that upgrade, the de-suspension fails with a message

```
general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP
```

followed usually by various tracebacks and attempts to fix, most of which has disappeared off the top of the screen before it can be read. The keyboard and mouse are then completely dead, so I have to reboot, after which it informs me there has been a System Failure and do I want to report it (which I do, though my modem does not show much activity to indicate any report is actually being sent).

My hardware is i386 32bit using a Gigabyte Motherboard.

Once rebooted, the system works fine, with no evidence if hardware failure.

Comment: I understand what you're talking about but "wake" and "resume" are the common-use terms for what you're talking about when you say "de-suspend". They'll net you better results when searching.

Comment: And here's a pile of other people, seemingly with your problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774150

Comment: And: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040169/experiencing-suspend-resume-problem-after-latest-kernel-update-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is supported until April 2019, you can check that by calling `ubuntu-support-status` (takes a while!), see https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life.

Comment: How exactly is the automatic de-suspension done?

Comment: Yes, the bug is now visible on launchpad, but no attempts to fix it thus far.

Comment: The de-suspension was done by rtcwake(8). Also, I have now established that, if suspended by pm-hibernate (as opposed to pm-suspend), or if completely shut-down, rtcwake still brings it up at the appointed time.

Comment: After downgrading intel-microcode 3.20180425.1 to previous version 2.20140122.1, wakeup after suspend works again for me...

Comment: There seem to be many versions between 2.20140122.1 and  3.20180425.1, for example 3.20180312.0~ubuntu14.04.1, so why did you go back so far? Also, what is the procedure for performing such a revert?

Comment: I simply chose the only other package version listed by synaptic for intel-microcode on my laptop. Maybe other versions show up with other configs. In any case I used the "force version" option in the package menu of synaptic, and then the option to hold it against updates. I don't master apt-get enough but it must be possible to do the same from command line. Hope this helps.